# Single feeder for multiple scenarios

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm looking for the way to use single feeder in multiple scenarios.

```
object Scenarios {
  val users = csv("users.csv").circular
  val sc1 = scenario("Scenario1").feed(users). ...
  val sc2 = scenario("Scenario2").feed(users). ...
}

class TestSim extends Simulation {
  setUp(
    Scenarios.sc1.inject(rampUsers(12) over (12 minutes))
  , Scenarios.sc2.inject(rampUsers(12) over (12 minutes))
  )
}
```

In this example both scenarios read users starting from the first record in the csv file. Is it possible to provide them single source of users?

Comment: Sounds interesting, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Meiko I don't want to have same user running different scenarios simultaneously.

Comment: although I'm aware this was asked 5 years ago, have you ever found a solution to this? I have a usecase exactly like this, in addition to sharing a session attribute field from one scenario to another and that field is generated per user in my feeder

Comment: @as1216 sorry, the latest version I have dramatically chaneged approvch for scenarios. At this point it's hard to tell if any workarround was found